# Почему не получается удалить куки?

Tags: php, cookie

Есть файл cookie.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE["page_visit"])) {
        setcookie("page_visit", ++$_COOKIE["page_visit"], time() + 3600);
    }
    else {
        setcookie("page_visit", 1, time() + 3600);
    }
```

После ввода логина и пароля на странице sign_in.php пользователь попадает на страницу admin.php, в коде которой подключается файл cookie.php.
В файле admin.php есть ссылка на logout.php:

```
<?php
    require_once "cookie.php";
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
                echo "<h1 style='text-align: center'>Админ панель</h1>";
                echo $_SESSION["user_login"] . ", добро пожаловать!<br>";
                echo "Вы посещали эту страницу: " . $_COOKIE["page_visit"] . "<br>";
                echo "<a href='logout.php'>Выход из аккаунта</a>";
            } 
            else {
                echo "Вы не вошли в аккаунт. У вас нет доступа к этой странице.<br>";
                echo "<a href='index.php'>На главную</a>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Проблема конкретно с logout.php. Куки почему-то не удаляется после нажатия на ссылку "Выход из аккаунта", расположенную на странице admin.php. Если снова залогиниться, то счётчик page_visit не сброситься.
logout.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    $_SESSION = [];
    setcookie("page_visit", "", time() - 1, "/");
    echo "Вы вышли из аккаунта<br>";
    unset($_COOKIE["page_visit"]);
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), "" , time() - 1, "/");
    }
    
    session_destroy();
    echo "<a href='sign_in.php'>Авторизоваться</a>";
```

**Прикрепил четыре скриншота с порядком своих действий на сайте. Как видно число посещений не становится равным 1 после релогина, т. е. по какой-то причине удаление куки в файле logout.php не срабатывает.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, потому что куку вы установили на одной странице, а удалить пытаетесь на другой, пути не совпадают и удаления не происходит

Comment: У меня все страницы находятся в корневой папке сайта. Поэтому пути должны совпадать

Comment: Насколько я понимаю если все страницы сайта находятся в корневой папке, то куку я могу удалять где угодно, т. к. действие куки распространяется на все страницы

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете. Сейчас запустил этот код у себя — у меня всё отлично удалилось, ищите проблему в другом месте

Comment: @andreymal ок, буду искать.